# memory leak in android.os.PowerManager

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks, powermanager, android-powermanager

I have identified memory leak, with following report from Eclipse Memory Analyzer

```
mBuffer android.graphics.Bitmap
'- mDrawBitmap com.bilickib.android.charts.PieChartView
   '- pieChartView mine.PieChartFragment
      '- mCurrentPrimaryItem com.bilickib.android.charts.PieChartFragmentPagerAdapter
         '- pieChartFragmentPagerAdapter com.bilickib.android.charts.PieChartHolder
            '- pieChartHolder com.bilickib.android.charts.Activity
               '- mContext android.os.PowerManager
                  '- mPowerManager android.view.ViewRootImpl
                     '- this$0 android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver
                        '- referent java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference
```

I do not use PowerManager in my code at all. How could it hold reference to my class?
PieChartView has big bitmap and causes memory leak for me.

edit:
I observe the issue on android 4.4.2 device. Checking android 4.4.3 change log, I see `Power Manager display wakelock fix` but I am unable to find more details what was fixed and symptoms of the bug.